# How to evaluate sum only when the function is specified explicitly?

Tags: summation

How does one instruct Mathematica to perform the following infinite sum only if the function `U` is specified explicitly?

```
ωn = 2 π n;
Sum[(ωn^2 + D[U[x], x])/(ωn^2 + k^2 + D[U[x], x]), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Currently the sum evaluates with an error message ``Sum::div: Sum does not converge."

Comment: Isn't that what is happening already? In other words, in your code `Sum` returns unevaluated, with a warning. If you don't want the warning, you could use `Quiet@Sum[...]`. You can still use the return value further.

Comment: "...function is specified explicitly"... what do you mean by that?  Of course you put in a *function*.  Do you mean instead "...if the sum *converges*"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think OP meant "only when `U[x]` has been assigned a specific value".

Comment: If you mean when `U[x]` has a value, then you could do something like `sum /; U[x] === Unevaluated[U[x]] := Sum[ ... ]`, and use `sum` where you would use `Sum[ ... ]`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I want to evaluate the sum if and only if the explicit form of the function U[x] is specified. The convergence of the sum depends on the choice of U[x].

Comment: As a side comment, irrespective of the specific form of function`U` I'd consider pulling the `D[U[x],x]` outside the sum because as it stands, the derivative is recalculated in every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this accurately tends to the needs of the question but I guess it's a start:

```
sum[U_?((Head[#]===Symbol//Not)&), var_,k_]:=Module[{dU=D[U,var]},
   Sum[((2 π n)^2 + dU)/((2 π n)^2 + k^2 + dU), 
     {n, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 ]
```

In a nutshell, `sum` evaluates when `U` is *not* a symbol.

Obviously this is not a foolproof way to check if there is a function defined with that head. I suspect that a more thorough solution would have to go through the `DownValues` and perhaps `OwnValues` (check thoroughly what kind of definitions are associated with symbol `U`).

Comment: This does it -- thanks!

Comment: Great to know it helps; you're welcome